# If $X$ is a Riemann surface, does $T_p^*X$ have complex dimension $1$ or $2$?

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, riemann-surfaces

$X$ is 1-dimensional complex manifold but why does $T_p^*X$ have dimension 2 over $\mathbb{C}$? 
Shouldn't a tangent space of an $n$-dimensional manifold over a field $F$ have dimension $n$ over $F$?

Comment: Can you provide the reference where it says that it is of dimension 2?

Comment: @JohnMa  p.62 of Otto Forster's book <Riemann surfaces> says $\mathbb{C} d z\vert_a \oplus \mathbb{C} d \bar{z} \vert_a = T_a^*X =T_a^{1,0} \oplus  T_a^{0,1}$

Comment: where $\mathbb{C}dz\vert_a=\{c\cdot dz\vert_a \ \vert  \ c\in\mathbb{C}\}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Forster means the complexified cotangent bundle of $X$, that is the complex vector bundle obtained by $\left(T_pX\right)^{\vee}\otimes_{\mathbb{R}}\mathbb{C}$; its complex dimension at any point is $2$.

**UPDATE**: Some book.

1. Daniel Huybrechts - *Complex Geometry. An Introduction*, chapter 2, section 1;
2. Raymond O. Wells, Jr., Oscar Garcia-Prada - *Differential Analysis on Complex Manifolds*, chapter 1, section 3.

Comment: For clarity, this is the *complexified* cotangent bundle, not the complex cotangent bundle.

Comment: Sorry for the mistake.